# Can't make a histogram out of a reactive data frame in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to using R and shinyapps. I am trying to make an app that makes different graphs based on the inputs made on a table by the user. The table updates a data frame when changes are made. The code is the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(

# Application title

titlePanel("Editable Dataframe and Plot"),

# Sidebar

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
DTOutput("my_datatable"),
actionButton("go",label = "Plot Data")
),

                # Show plot
                mainPanel(
                  plotOutput("my_plot")
                )

)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

#initialize a blank dataframe
v <- reactiveValues(data = {
data.frame(x = numeric(5))
})

#output the datatable based on the dataframe (and make it editable)
output$my_datatable <- renderDT({
DT::datatable(v$data, editable = TRUE)
})

#when there is any edit to a cell, write that edit to the initial dataframe
#check to make sure it's positive, if not convert
observeEvent(input$my_datatable_cell_edit, {
#get values
info = input$my_datatable_cell_edit
i = as.numeric(info$row)
j = as.numeric(info$col)
k = as.numeric(info$value)
if(k < 0){ #convert to positive if negative
k <- k * -1
}

                #write values to reactive
                v$data[i,j] <- k

})

#render plot
output$my_plot <- renderPlot({
z <- v$x
hist(z)
})

}

# Run the application

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I keep getting that x must be numerical even though I've tried various syntax. I've also tried adding certain conditionals so that the histogram does not load if there's no input by the user, but it has also not done anything. I know this is a very simple matter, but I need help. :[ I tried searching for similar questions and found some that were related, but the kind of information they're managing is different.

Comment: I edited the code to remove lots of backslashes which should not have been there.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you very much.

Comment: `x` is a column of the data.frame `data` which is an element of `v`, i.e. use `v$data$x`.

Comment: @stefan Thank you so much! This solved my problem. Could you maybe post your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as the accepted answer for the thread?